# In auto scaling AMI launch how to copy my private key file in new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I have a instance in aws and private key file is authorized keys which is stored in .ssh path.When auto scaling AMI is launched then that file should copy to new server in the same location i.e .ssh how can we do it by using Cloud formation template.

what code or what commands should I keep in CFN template.

Thanks

Comment: To clarify... Are you asking how to configure Auto Scaling in a CloudFormation template to specify an SSH key? Wouldn't you just specify the `KeyName` in the Launch Configuration? (This assumes you have previously uploaded the public half of the keypair to AWS.)

Comment: Yes ,New Autoscaling instance must have new changes added to  #vi /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

Comment: Yes , I have one cloud formation template which will triggers for new autoscaling instance launch.I have one file i.e  located here  /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys file in previoud instance .What are the changes happened this file should come in the same path in the new instance when I connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new ami with your private key stored and use the ami in your CloudFormation template.

```
steps: 
1. launch new instance from the current ami you are using
2. ssh to your instance and copy the private key file
3. stop the instance in aws console and right click the instance -> image -> create image
4. use your new ami as EcsAmiId
```

Comment: ssh to your instance and copy the private key file..this is manual step It should copy automatically when CFN is triggered for new instance generation.I need what json or yaml i should write to happen this

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `user data` script in your CF template where you are describing your EC2 instance. `user data` script is just a normal bash script that will be executed when the instance boots up, which means that you can automate any such task as copying files using it, which you would otherwise needed to do manually.

You can also pre-bake a custom AMI, or in other words, create a new AMI that has all the settings already in place and use that AMI in your CF template instead of whatever default AMI you are using right now.

Answer (score 0):

A Keypair can be created within the EC2 console, or the public half of an existing Keypair can be uploaded to EC2.

Once this is done, an Amazon EC2 instance can be launched with a reference to this Keypair. Software on the instance (if using an Amazon Linux AMI) will automatically copy the public half of the nominated keypair to the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

This applies for launching an EC2 instance via any method, eg console, API, CloudFormation.

This is much easier than trying to manipulate the `authorized_keys` file yourself via User Data.